# Can you please explain why the Binding not working for DisplayMemberPath of ItemsControl?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, dependency-properties, itemscontrol

Can any one please explain why the Binding is not working for DisplaymemberPath of ItemsControl?

And I checked with Reflector DisplayMemberPath of ItemsControl is only Dependency Property,and also Bindable attribute set True only.

**XAML:**

```
  <ComboBox x:Name="display" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding NewAddress.TelePhone}" ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}"/>
```

**Person Class:**

```
public class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
        persons = new ObservableCollection<NewAddress>();
        persons.Add(new NewAddress() { TelePhone = "MyNo" });
        persons.Add(new NewAddress() { TelePhone = "MyNo1" });
        persons.Add(new NewAddress() { TelePhone = "MyNo2" });
        persons.Add(new NewAddress() { TelePhone = "MyNo3" });
    }

    private ObservableCollection<NewAddress> persons;

    public ObservableCollection<NewAddress> Persons
    {
        get { return persons; }
        set { persons = value; }
    }

}
```

**Address Class:**

```
 public class NewAddress
{
    public string  TelePhone { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Post your data Item. (the person class I guess), and also the Address class

Comment: If you leave out the DiplayMemberPath do you at least get rows with repeating text?

Comment: You have a serious problem with your naming conventions.

Comment: @HighCore:I just used this Naming convention for simple sample purpose only

Comment: It is unclear to me if your `ComboBox.ItemsSource` is a Collection of Person class, or a collection of Address class. Also, why are you adding items of type Address to a collection named "Persons". That's rather ambiguous and misleading.

Answer (score 4):

DisplayMemberPath is the actual name of the property, not a binding to the property. Change your XAML code to the following:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="display" DisplayMemberPath="TelePhone" ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}"/>
```

Comment: So when we set Binding to DisplayMemberPath is always not working?

Comment: @Ravuthasamy Did that fix the stated problem or not?